# Print sql query on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a SQL query in my PHP file that makes use of some variables in it. I want to print the query itself on the localhost to check as to whether the entire query is been executed or not.

**My query is like this:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE col01 LIKE '%$abc%',$db);
```

I am trying to print the query using echo $result but get `Resource id #25` on localhost. I want to print `Select * FROM ...` as the output. Is there any way?

Comment: (1) Stop using `mysql_query`.  Seriously.  It's deprecated, and has been for a while.  (2) You're currently echoing the result resource `mysql_query` gave you, which is the result from running the query -- not the query itself.

Comment: I would really love to see **any** question about the mysql_*() family **not** be spammed with "use PDO". This is like a question about Harley-Davidson carburettors being answered with "use a Honda dfi". Sorry for the rant, but I had to get that off my chest. Better now.

Comment: @EugenRieck: It's more like asking a question about your Pinto and being told to get a real car before you die in a fire.  It's usually a better answer than the one the asker wanted.

Comment: @cHao Excellent example! It's the one answer, that is guaranteed to **not** help the Pinto owner.

Comment: @EugenRieck: Except that [it's kinda the right answer](http://auto.howstuffworks.com/1971-1980-ford-pinto12.htm).   There are numerous reasons to switch, not least of which is that sometime in the not-too-distant future, all the `mysql_query`-based code out there will no longer run by default.

Comment: @cHao It might be the **right** answer (from your point of view), but it is definitly the most **unhelpfull** answer. Besides, the myth of `mysql_*()` no longer working "in the near future" is quite old. But enough - I do not at all dispute the underlying truth, is just want to point out, that unhelpfull comments are ... unhelpfull.

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You are missing a double quote: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM sample WHERE col01 LIKE '%$abc%'`"`,$db).

That said, what stops you from

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM sample WHERE col01 LIKE '%$abc%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db);
echo $sql;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using PDO (and you should, the old mysql_ functions are deprecated and insecure) you could just use [PDOStatement->queryString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php#pdostatement.props.querystring) property to view the query at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Store as a variable $sql

Its normal, first  you need to fetch that resource obj

And anyway you missing a double quote,

example.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE col01 LIKE '%$abc%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($line = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $line->colname ."\n";
}



   echo "\n" . ' query: ' . $sql
```

And from **PHP 5.5.0** and beyond use mysqli

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM sample WHERE col01 LIKE '%$abc%'";
    if ($result = $mysqliobj->query($sql)) { 
            while($line= $result->fetch_object()){ 
                echo = $line->colname ."\n"; 

            } 
        } 

     echo "\n" . ' query: ' . $sql
or print_r($mysqliobj->info); # store las query
```

Comment: For reference, mysqli has been around for ages...long before 5.5.  I think it was there even in 5.0.

Comment: for shure, btw the old one was official deprecated from 5.5 mysqli rocks :3